# Postgis query for nearest neighbor returns distant coordinates

Tags: postgis, gps, query, nearest-neighbor

I have schema for a table called "places" that looks like this with about 6000 rows:

```
name | county| long | lat | the_geom | id

Tuthilltown | Ulster | -74.1789 | 41.6843271513 | 0101000020E61000004850FC18738B52C0974C370898D74440 |  1
```

the_geom was created following a tutorial from the lat/long of each places like so:

```
UPDATE places SET the_geom = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || long || ' ' || lat || ')',4326);
```

These are places scattered across the state of NY.

I am currently in the far north, but when I attempt to search for my nearest neighbor, it returns points in the far east e.g. Montauk.

The basic query for nearest neighbor is supposed to look like this:

```
SELECT name, lat, long
FROM places
ORDER BY the_geom <-> st_setsrid(st_makepoint( "my coordinates" ),4326)
LIMIT 1;
```

My coordinates are not stored but rather given on the fly from my phone.

To fix this, I have thus far attempted to create an index on this table, but I am not sure how to search against the index or if it would give me the proper results.

Is this an issue with psql or is it my query (more likely)?

Comment: Wild guess: are "my coordinates" swapped lat for lon?

Comment: Couple things were a little off it looks like. Yes, the coordinates were reversed from my current location. Also, the data_type for the_geom was geometry and not geography. I am not sure which of those two fixed it but I'm glad it's working now! Thanks!!